# How to get a SimpleXMLElement object in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to parse an object which contains a SimpleXMLElement attribute but I didn't succeed to get the SimpleXMLElement attribute contents.
I have a variable $field and I would like to access $field->element attribute. When I do **var_dump($field)**, this is the result:

```
object(JFormFieldRadio)[267]
  protected 'type' => string 'Radio' (length=5)
  ...
  protected 'element' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[192]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=5)
          'name' => string 'listradio' (length=9)
          'type' => string 'radio' (length=5)
          'default' => string '0' (length=1)
          'label' => string 'Liste radio' (length=11)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'option' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'test 1' (length=6)
          1 => string 'Option 1' (length=8)
          2 => string 'Option 2' (length=8)
```

If I do **var_dump($field->element)** It returns null so If i try to access **$field->element->option** I have an error (**Trying to get property of non-object**).
I also tried to check the object type

```
if ($field->element instanceof SimpleXMLElement)
```

but it returns false.
Actually, I would like to access to the option array. 
Is is possible to access $field->element and to parse it?

Finally, I resolved it by extending the JFormFieldRadio and adding a public method to get the necessary information from the element attribute.

Comment: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFormFieldRadio.html

Comment: You can't access to protected element outside the class.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Now I understand why I couldn't access it.